# Pager numbers do not match URI string in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pager

How can I make the pager numbers match the URI string?

For example : When I click on number 3 in pager to turn to page 3 but the the URI is "?page=2" instead of "?page=3". This pagination isn't normal as any other pagination I've met before. How can I fix it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe with a combination of query alter and htaccss.
It's probably not worth your time though.

Comment: I too badly need to know a good way. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by implementing [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), and [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7).

With the first hook, you alter the links that are being output from Drupal; you would increase the value of `$options['query']['page']`.
With the second hook, you alter the links being received from Drupal; you should find the `'?page='` string in the URL, and decrease the number after that string.

Keep in mind that `$_GET['page']` can be a string like `'1,2,4,5,6'` if the page has more than one pager. See the code of [pager_find_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_find_page/7).

Also, `hook_url_outbound_alter()` receive the query parameters in `$options`, while `hook_url_inbound_alter()` receives just a string for the URL, which also contains the query part.

Answer (score 1):

The **page** attribute in the URL is used directly in the query, so if ommitted, **page** will get 0 as a value. It's normal because Drupal do pagin things like this.

Now if you need to change this, you have to work arround query alters for every query, to add +1 to the limit() or range() methods.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to know exactly where to do this ?

Comment: You must provide an example of the query you wan't to alter. Generaly, the [hook_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7 "hook_query_alter()") is used for this purpose

Comment: This is a complicated way, considering there is a simpler way to change links output from Drupal, and the ones Drupal receives.